# Export python script with dependencies to other Operating System

Tags: python, python-2.7, cross-platform, pynput

I want to export the following code from a MAC with python 2.7 to a Windows with the following dependency (pynput) which I am importing from pip.
I'd like the person to be able to run the file in their terminal without installing pynput.
I tried converting the file to an executable but it didn't even work on my machine.

Here is the code:

```
import thread
import random
import time
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Controller, Button

mouse = Controller()
trigger = False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global trigger
    if str(button) == "Button.middle" and pressed:
        trigger = True
        print "Middle button has been pressed"

    if str(button) == "Button.middle" and pressed == False:
        print "Middle button has been unpressed"
        trigger = False

def loop_thread(threadName, delay):
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
        if trigger == True:
            sleep_time = random.uniform(0.02, 0.12)x
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def listener_thread(threadName, delay):
    with Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()

try:
   thread.start_new_thread( loop_thread, ("Thread-1", 0.025 ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( listener_thread, ("Thread-2", 0.25, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

Do you know if there's any way to make python scripts cross platform and to include dependencies in said script?

Comment: This may help, there is a way. :) https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/ You may have to do the necessary edits and freeze it for each distributions.

Answer (score 0):

The executable need to be made on the same operating system to work, so no freezing, Cython or nuitka. You could try [pex](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex), I think it works across OS, you will have to ship your programm and the pex file.